# Android Camera Preview Is locked after releasing

Tags: android, android-camera

**After the picture is captured**,  and then  trying to **run** the application **again** a black screen appears with no preview , and if I want to run the camera or any other application using the camera a message appears that the **camera is locked!** 
Any Hints or ideas why ?

Thanks in advance.

```
    public class Capture extends Activity {
        private   Camera mCamera=null;
        private ViewCamera mPreview=null;
        public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
        Mat jpegData;
        Mat bgrMat;

        private BaseLoaderCallback mOpenCVCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
            @Override
            public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                    Log.i("", "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    // Create and set View
                    // setContentView(R.layout.camera);
                    jpegData = new Mat();
                    bgrMat = new Mat();
                }
                    break;
                default: {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                }
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.camera);
            // Create an instance of Camera
             Log.i("", "Trying to load OpenCV library");
            if (!OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_6, this,
                    mOpenCVCallBack)) {
                Log.e("", "Cannot connect to OpenCV Manager");
            }
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            Log.d("", "getCameraInstance *");

            // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
            mPreview = new ViewCamera(this, mCamera);
            Log.d("", "new view * ");
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
            Log.d("", "frame layout * ");
            preview.addView(mPreview);
            Log.d("", "addview * ");
        }

        /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
        public Camera getCameraInstance() {
            if(this.mCamera==null)
                try {
                    this.mCamera = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera
                                                    // instance
                    Log.d("", " open camera * ");

                    // c.lock();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
                    Log.d("", "can't open camera ");

                }
            return this.mCamera; // returns null if camera is unavailable
        }


        /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
        private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
            // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
            // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

            File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    "MyCameraApp");
            // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
            // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

            // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            // Create a media file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                    .format(new Date());
            File mediaFile;
            if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
                mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                        + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
            } else {
                return null;
            }

            return mediaFile;
        }

        private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Log.d("", "on picture taken starts ");


                File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                Log.d("", "file get media file ");

                if (pictureFile == null) {
                    Log.d("",
                            "Error creating media file, check storage permissions ");
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    Log.d("", "File try save ");

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    fos.write(byteArray);
                    fos.close();
                    Log.d("", "File saved ");

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d("", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                mCamera.startPreview();
                Log.d("", "start preview after saving * ");
            }

        };


        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("", "on touch starts * ");
            System.gc();
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, mPicture);
            Log.d("", "taken pic * ");
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        private final ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
            public void onShutter() {
                Log.d("", "start shutter * ");
               /* AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                mgr.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);*/
                Log.d("", "end shutter * ");
            }
        };


}
```

Surfaceview

```
public class ViewCamera extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public ViewCamera(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        Log.d("", "start view camera constructor * ");
        mCamera = camera;
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        Log.d("", "view camera constructor holder and callback * ");
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the
        // preview.

        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                Log.d("", "surface created camera !=null * ");

                Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

                if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    Log.d("", "camera orientation not landscape ");
                    params.set("orientation", "portrait"); //
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                }
                //mCamera.setParameters(params);

                Log.d("", "surface created start preview * ");

                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // check if device has camera
    private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            Log.d("", "there is a camera ");

            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            Log.d("", "there is no camera ");

            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
     * Camera.Parameters parameters) { Camera.Size result = null;
     * Log.d("", "start getbestsize * ");
     * 
     * for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) { if
     * (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) { if (result == null) {
     * result = size; } else { int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
     * int newArea = size.width * size.height;
     * 
     * if (newArea > resultArea) { result = size; } } } }
     * 
     * return (result); }
     */
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
        Log.d("", "surface destroy starts * ");

            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            Log.d("", "call back null * ");

            this.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
            Log.d("", "remove call back * ");
            if (mCamera != null) {
                Log.d("", "camera not null * ");
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                Log.d("", "preview stopped * ");

            mCamera.release();
            Log.d("", "release camera * ");

            mCamera = null;
            Log.d("", "camera null * ");

            Log.d("surfaceDestroyed", "surfaceDestroyed");
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        Log.d("", "surface changed starts * ");

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            Log.d("", "surface changed get surface=null * ");

            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            Log.d("", "surface changed stop preview  * ");

            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        Log.d("", "surface changed parameters  * ");

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        // Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(w, h, parameters);

        /*
         * if (size != null) { parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width,
         * size.height); mCamera.setParameters(parameters); }
         */
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            Log.d("", "surface changedresume start preview * ");

            // if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            // }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("",
                    "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you move the release code into `onPause()` of your Activity, as recommended [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#release-camera)?

Comment: yes it still the same !